# How to launch VS 2010 so it opens a sln file and selects a specific solution configuration in the environment

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-macros

I work with a team on a large project developed for multiple platforms. We used to have a separate sln file for each platform so i could chose which platform i want to work on by opening the appropriate sln file. Recently we merged all sln files into a single one. I would like to create new shortcuts for myself - one for each platform - which would launch VS 2010 opening the solution and setting the selected solution configuration to "Debug|PlatformName" for each PlatformName we use.

I have been reading on the net about possible command line arguments to pass devenv.exe that would select it and it seems there's two approaches:

1. switches - there seems to be none that sets the current configuration in the environment without building or deploying or cleaning
2. commands (devenv /command "..."). A list of commands with arguments is to be found here but once again i see nothing suitable for the purpose:
   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c338aexd(v=vs.80).aspx

Thanks in advance for the answers.

Comment: A program like VS just doesn't offer command line arguments when the user can trivially change the selection.  It is available on the toolbar, "Solution Platforms" combobox.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can create a VS launcher by yourself with a scripting/automation tool like AutoHotKey (http://www.autohotkey.com/) or something like that.
With these kind of tool you should be able to run VS, wait it to load, and then change the combo to select your solution configuration.